# Define global BeforeMap and AfterMap callbacks for AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I know about the feature of defining a Before/AfterMap callback on the map level for a given type pair. However, I'm searching for a solution to define a global Before/AfterMap function somehow, which would apply to every defined type map.

In most of my DTOs I have a mechanism which prevents changed notifications temporarly with the BeginUpdate/EndUpdate pattern. I would like AutoMapper to wrap the mapping between these calls whenever the target type supports it.

I've looked through questions here and the AutoMapper docs but haven't found a native solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found a porposed solution, but haven't tested it completely yet.

After all of my maps are registered, I would do something like this:

```
var typeMaps = Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps();
foreach (var typeMap in typeMaps)
{
    typeMap.AddBeforeMapAction(...);
    typeMap.AddAfterMapAction(...);
}
```

Comment: did you ever get anywhere with this? Do you have an example of the final result.

Comment: I am facing same issue. I am registering an expression which is calling a method in .AddAfterMapAction. But it is not calling the method while mapping. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60373957/automapper-addaftermapaction-not-calling-method