# Automapper AddAfterMapAction not calling method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, automapper-9

I am using global configuration for Automapper profile mapping.

```
public class StudentProfile : Profile
{
    public StudentProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Student, StudentVM>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.school, src => src.Ignore());
    }
}
```

**Mapper Configuration**

```
public static class Configuration
{
    public static IMapper InitializeAutoMapper()
    {
        MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new StudentProfile());
        });

        config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        return config.CreateMapper();
    }
}
```

Now I am adding **.AddAfterMapAction** using Expression.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var mapper = Configuration.InitializeAutoMapper();

            foreach (var item in mapper.ConfigurationProvider.GetAllTypeMaps())
            {
                Expression<Action<int>> beforeMapAction = (x) => Test(x);
                item.AddAfterMapAction(beforeMapAction);
            }

            var dest = mapper.Map<Student, StudentVM>(StudentService.GetStudent());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
    public static void Test(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("X = {0}", x);
    }
```

It is not invoking the Test method when I am mapping using this line: `var dest = mapper.Map<Student, StudentVM>(StudentService.GetStudent());`

Am I doing anything wrong here. As it should call the Test method while mapping.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási Thanks for your reply. it only allow Expression in.AddAfterMapAction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify maps after `MappingConfiguration` is instantiated. Once a `TypeMap` is built, the execution plan is created and can't change.

You need to move that `AfterMap` configuration into where you're configuring.

Comment: Do you mean after cfg.AddProfile() but before config.CreateMapper()?